# Best practice to prevent PHP URL Parameter mischif

Tags: php, url-parameters

We've recently found one of our client's PHP websites suffering from attacks on a page that passes URL Parameters to select/show a product.

The code is such that they "should not" be able to cause problems due to it simply selecting a product Id, but they are sending thousands of queries looking for some vulnerability and consuming many server resources in their attempts. We've blocked the offending IP addresses but of course, they just move to different ones.

Question: Are URL Parameters no longer recommended for simple page content display?

I'm thinking of updating the pages to use a $_SESSION value and just reset that each time a new page selection is made.

I've been reading up on "URL Parameter pollution" and see how it is being used more often to exploit websites.

Comment: The vulnerability doesn't come from them being in URL parameters. The vulnerabilities come from how the application uses parameters, e.g. SQL injection attacks. As long as you use the parameters safely, it doesn't matter if they're in query parameters or POST data.

Comment: You can't use session data for parameters that come from the client. That's for saving data created on the server between calls.

Comment: It sounds like the problem is that someone is flooding you with requests, regardless of what those requests actually are.  This doesn't have anything to do with URL parameters.  Are you instead looking for information on how to handle a DOS attack?  (Since the only real problem described is... *"consuming many server resources in their attempts"*)

Comment: "consuming many server resources in their attempts" Yes this is the main issue, though I do want to make sure that they can not exploit the current parameters.